# table header repeating in xml data table

Tags: php, xml

Im pulling some data from an xml on a separate site and trying to display that data in a table, i can pull the data but when i tried to display the data in a table for each row i got the table headers, now i know why this is happening (because the table header echo is being called for every row) but i cant see how to fix it.

```
<?php
$url = "http://elcu.herobo.com/testarea/include/cd_catalog.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach($xml->CD as $cd){
    echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' width'90%' id='1' class='tablesorter'><thead><tr> <th>Title</th> <th>Artist</th> <th>Company</th><th>Price</th></thead><tbody>";
    echo "<td width='25%'> ".$cd->TITLE."</td>";
    echo "<td width='25%'> ".$cd->ARTIST."</td>";
    echo "<td width='25%'> ".$cd->COMPANY."</td>";
    echo "<td width='25%'> ".$cd->PRICE."</td>";
    echo "</tbody></table>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean:

```
<?php
$url = "http://elcu.herobo.com/testarea/include/cd_catalog.xml";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' width'90%' id='1' class='tablesorter'>\n";
echo "<thead><tr> <th>Title</th> <th>Artist</th> <th>Company</th><th>Price</th></thead>";
echo "<tbody>";

foreach($xml->CD as $cd){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='25%'> ".$cd->TITLE."</td>";
    echo "<td width='25%'> ".$cd->ARTIST."</td>";
    echo "<td width='25%'> ".$cd->COMPANY."</td>";
    echo "<td width='25%'> ".$cd->PRICE."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Note that you called `table` inside your foreach loop, and you also didn't specify the start and end of the row with `tr`

Answer (score 0):

i think the table will come before the foreach loop so that each record will create a row rather than a table

```
 echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' width'90%' id='1' class='tablesorter'><thead><tr> <th>Title</th> <th>Artist</th> <th>Company</th><th>Price</th></thead><tbody>";

foreach($xml->CD as $cd)

  {




  echo "<td width='25%'> ".$cd->TITLE."</td>";

  echo "<td width='25%'> ".$cd->ARTIST."</td>";

  echo "<td width='25%'> ".$cd->COMPANY."</td>";

  echo "<td width='25%'> ".$cd->PRICE."</td>";


  }

 echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: i tried this and it breaks the table and calls all the data as one line of text